# точка входа в win32 приложении

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Вопрос немного странный однако, попробую сформулировать.
Скорее он звучит так "что делают в win32 project на с++".
В обычном консольном приложении точка входа обычный int main().
Насколько я знаю, точкой входа в win32 project является WinMain, выходит в win32 project работают с чистым winapi (windows.h) верно? Однако, если это так то почему на нем спокойно запускаются приложения через int main()?

Comment: В c++ точкой входа всегда будет `main()`. Вопрос ваш непонятен

Comment: @gil9red, точкой входа будет то, что укажут в PE. Очевидно, что вопрос по windows, а не рафинированному C++. Но вопрос всё равно непонятен, с этим согласен.

Comment: Попробую переформулировать. Когда используют WinMain функцию, а когда main()

Comment: Вот тут есть отличный ответ: [WINMAIN and main() in C++ (Extended)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871617/winmain-and-main-in-c-extended). Было бы круто, если бы кто-то его перевёл и сюда вставил.

Comment: Разобрался наконец то, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор между main и другими (нестандартными) точками входа определяется параметрами компилятора. Например, в Visual C++:

- При указании параметра `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`, точкой входа является реализованная компилятором функция mainCRTStartup, которая вызывает реализованную программистом функцию main/wmain.
- При указании параметра `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`, точкой входа является реализованная компилятором функция WinMainCRTStartup, которая вызывает реализованную программистом функцию WinMain/wWinMain.
- Если также указан параметр `/ENTRY`, вместо указанных выше точек входа будет использована явно указанная функция.

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol)

Функции с префиксом "w" используются со строковыми параметрами типа WCHAR, а без него - с обычным char. Если указать параметры неправильно, будет ошибка компилятора (что-то вроде "Нельзя перегрузить WinMain"); однако выбор между main и wmain не обязательно должен соответствовать параметру Character set в свойствах проекта.

---

При выборе типа проекта "Win32 Project", начальное значение параметра SUBSYSTEM будет WINDOWS, поэтому используется WinMain. Однако можно поменять настройки, так чтобы использовалась main или вообще какая-то другая функция, и весь функционал WinAPI будет работать точно так же. Иными словами, WinMain - это просто традиционная точка входа для приложений WinAPI, но никакого правила, что "*Приложение Win32 всегда должно использовать WinMain*" не существует.