# Точка входа в программу

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++

Почему при точке входа `WinMain/wWinMain` не запускается консоль. А при точке входа `main` - запускается. Как это работает?

И как компилятор понимает, что `WinMain/wWinMain` является точкой входа, если стандартной является `main`. Как работать с точкой входа `main` без запуска консоли, используя заголовочный файл *windows.h*?

Ещё хотелось бы спросить, где можно найти про это структурированную информацию (почитать про это, как это работает).

Comment: [/SUBSYSTEM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> как компилятор понимает что WinMain/wWinMain является точкой входа, если стандартной является main

Стандарт лишь определяет, что компилятор обязан поддерживать использование точки входа с прототипом `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Стандарт не запрещает поддерживать любые другие точки входа. В случае Visual C++, точка входа определяется параметрами компоновщика [/SUBSYSTEM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2017) и [/ENTRY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2017). Когда параметр /SUBSYSTEM имеет значение "WINDOWS", а параметр /ENTRY не определен, точкой входа является функция WinMain.

> Как работать с точкой входа main без запуска консоли

Установив параметры компоновщика `/ENTRY:"mainCRTStartup" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. В диалоговом окне свойств проекта эти параметры расположены в "Linker - Advanced - Entry point" и "Linker - System - Subsystem" соответственно.

Подробное описание принципов выбора точки входа можно прочитать здесь:  [точка входа в win32 приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867472/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-win32-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Стандартных варианта `main` всё же [два, а не один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794523/176217).

Answer (score 0):

Понимает не компилятор, а линковщик. Когда он выполняет линковку для той или иного формата файла - консоли, оконного приложения или чего еще - он прилинковывает некий объектный файл с кодом стартапа, который выполняет инициализацию всяких вещей, как-то разбор кормандной строки и всякое другое, а потом, выполнив подготовку среды выполнения, вызывает ту самую "главную" функцию.

Которая может иметь разное имя для разных проектов.

`WinMain` - это просто соглашение, ничего мистически-сакрального в этом имени нет.