# Ошибка перегрузки функции WinMain

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Весь код , но при этом выдает ошибку `WinMain: функция не может быть перегружена`. Что делать? Сижу на Visual Studio 2017

Comment: `wWinMain` и следует убедится что подсистема стоит WINDOWS а не CONSOLE, и что включена поддержка UNICODE

Comment: UNICODE стоит, а как проверить подсистему?

Comment: Скорее всего и стоит CONSOLE, а как поменять?

Comment: @VTT Нет, не помогает

Comment: @Kaznachei что именно? Замена WinMain на wWinMain (или PWSTR на PSTR), по моим тестам, определенно устраняет указанную ошибку. А если бы у вас неверно была установлена подсистема, ошибка была бы другая.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ничего, я вместо `WinMain` написал `wWinMain` . Все заработало, спасибо. А в чем между ними разница ?

Comment: Точка входа WinMain используется с ANSI-строками (параметры WinMain должны быть типа char), а wWinMain - с широкими символами (WCHAR). У вас тип PWSTR эквивалентен WCHAR*, поэтому нужно использовать wWinMain. Так как у вас в примере параметры никак не используются, разницы на практике не видно. Вообще, подробно о точках входа в VC++  написано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867472/точка-входа-в-win32-приложении

Answer (score 1):

```
WinMain (
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nShowCmd
    );
```

Надо `LPSTR` вместо `PWSTR` для `WinMain`.